# How to integrate this menu into HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm learning canvas and I want to make a canvas app with grid like this. I don't know how to implement this.. Any ideas would be great. Thank you in advance.

[image: grid]

Comment: Start by learning to draw quads to a `<canvas>`  Do note, that once something is rasterized to a canvas, there is no longer a context that it is a shape, it's just pixels at that point so you will need to store where you drew your rectangles and do "collision detection" between the mouse click position and that data structure of collisions.  You can use a Quadtree or (since it's not that many shapes) just brute force compare against every shape.  Please post back when you have some code to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Y7m2e/

[image][image][image]

**Define some "menu buttons" (actually rectangles) and store them in an array:**

```
var rects=[];
rects.push({x:10,y:10,width:30,height:15,fillcolor:"red",isFilled:false});
rects.push({x:10,y:50,width:50,height:30,fillcolor:"blue",isFilled:false});
```

**Draw all the menu buttons that you have defined:**

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
        var rect=rects[i];
        if(rect.isFilled){
            ctx.fillStyle=rect.fillcolor;
            ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
            ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            ctx.strokeRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
            ctx.fillStyle="gold";
            ctx.fillText("ON",rect.x+5,rect.y+10);
        }else{
            ctx.fillStyle="gray";
            ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
            ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            ctx.strokeRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
            ctx.fillStyle="gold";
            ctx.fillText("OFF",rect.x+5,rect.y+10);
        }
    }
}
```

**Listen for mousedown events and toggle any menu button that was clicked**

```
function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Toggle menu "rects" when clicked
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
      var rect=rects[i];
      if(x>=rect.x && x<=rect.x+rect.width && y>=rect.y && y<=rect.y+rect.height)){
          rect.isFilled=!rect.isFilled;
      }
  }
  draw();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will start working on that. I will update post if I have any queries.